# Given a set of point sets, find points from each set with maximum total distance between them while each distance is larger than a threshold

Tags: algorithms, optimization

The title may be a bit confusing but the problem is this;

Lets assume I have 5 points in 4 groups (in total 20 points). What I want to achieve is;

-> Pick one point from each group (we will have 4 points at the end)

- whose pairwise distance is larger than a threshold and
- sum of pairwise distances is maximized.

For realization of parameters; group size is number of people in a scene, and points in a group is possible locations of each person. Point size can be increased to tens or hundreds for better estimation depending on computing resources but people count possible will not be larger than 20 or 30.

I hope, I could explained the question clear enough. If not, I will try to clarify better.

Thanks

Comment: There are only $5^4 = 625$ possible choices. Just try all of them.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus A generalized answer will be better. Group and point size can vary, so it may become inefficient to check all possible choices.

Comment: The answer could depend on the magnitude of your parameters. Do you expect both the number of groups and their size to grow to infinity? If so, do you expect them to be of comparable magnitude?

Comment: No, they will not grow to infinity. For realization of parameters; group size is number of people in a scene, and points in a group is possible locations of each person. Point size can be increased to tens or hundreds for better estimation depending on computing resources but people count possible will not be larger than 20 or 30.

Comment: You should update your question with all this information.

Comment: Don't add an addendum. Modify your original question to include all necessary information in one piece.

Comment: Do you care to pay due credit to the original source of the problem, such as adding a url or reference in the question?

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a clustering problem. Here, you you've seeking representative points (one of the convex hull vertices of each cluster). Does that describe your problem accurately?

Comment: @Apass.Jack this is from my own personal research.

Comment: @rrufai representative points should be selected regarding their distances from other cluster's representative points, not their own cluster's points. So it is a bit different than yours.

Comment: @UnfoX: You could start by taking the convex hull of each cluster. The representative points can then be found by brute force using only the vertices of the convex hulls. There might be an even smarter way. Could you provide an example in your question to help us visualize things a bit?